# Why p:ajax doesn´t update my h:outputText in primefaces 5 and JSF2?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, xhtml

I have a datatable with a filter

[image]

The filter work good but the result of filter doesn't work. I call ajax inside of p:inputText to try to refresh the result but doesn't work

```
<h:outputText value="Result"/><h:outputText id="sizeFilterMyWork" value="#{caseManagement.myWork.size()}" />
<h:outputText value="Filter" id="myCaseOutputTextSearch" />
<p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('myCaseTable').filter()" style="width:150px" >
   <p:ajax event="keyup" update="sizeFilterMyWork" listener="#{caseManagement.getSizefilteredMyWork}"></p:ajax>
</p:inputText>
```

In the bean I have the list of `myWork` (with get and set) and a list used for the filter (with get and set), when the page is load the result call the size of the list of my work, then, when I use the filter the datatable is shrinking (so it's work) but the number of result doesnt change. Ajax should call the method `getSizefilteredMyWork` and update the result but doesnt work

Bean

```
private List<Case> myWork = new ArrayList<Case>(); // get and set
private List<Case> filteredMyWork; //get and set
public int getSizefilteredMyWork(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
    return filteredMyWork.size();
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your listener method's return value is ignored but you don't need it because the `outputText` will get its value directly from `myWork`. It should get the size of the `filteredMyWork` list instead.

You could try replacing the `ìnputText` `p:ajax` with one in the `p:datatable`:

```
<p:ajax event="filter" process="@this" update="sizeFilterMyWork" />
```

Comment: Excelent consideration, I just change ``value="#{caseManagement.myWork.size()}`` by ``value="#{caseManagement.filteredMyWork.size()}``